# Chart.JS, date issues when upgrading to v3

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to upgrade Chart.js from a pretty old version to the most recent one. I have a Chart with some dates on the X axis, and while it worked just fine with the 2.* version, I have some issue related to the order of the dates with v3.

I have made a CodeSandbox for this issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-hofstadter-fh0c7?file=/src/index.js:0-5589

This is how the Chart is been generated from another piece of code. The blue line is abnormal with this version, while before the update the Chart was like this:

[image]

The date description for the X axis seems to be different too.

What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything changes you made for the new v3 version. There are several breaking changes. Please have a look at the [chart.js v3.x migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

Comment: My bad. I have updated the Codesandbox with all the stuff changed I've found. Seems just right at the moment. There are any other changes I've missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since chart.js v3 chart.js does not ship with a data adapter anymore, for your chart to work you will have to include one yourself: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-adapters

Also the legend needs to be configured in the plugins section as stated in the migration docs.

Working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-chebyshev-82goo?file=/src/index.js:5914-5917