# Am I missing a chart.js component or helper?

Tags: chart.js

I experimented with my code on the chartjs website (using their editor on one of their samples pages) and it works perfectly. When I copy and paste it into my page, the chart won't even render. When I delete the line "type: 'time'," the chart renders fine, but not with the intended x axis (which makes me think the rest of my code is OK). When I delete the entire 'scales' section, it also renders. It's something in that section that is tanking my chart. Am I missing a component or helper that is required for the 'time' type to function? I have the latest version of chart.js installed (3.7.0), but that's the only external script I have linked.

```
            scales: {
                    x: {
                        type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            unit:'month',
                        },
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Date'
                        }
                    },
            }
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: I found it: Luxon adapter required...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart.JS, date issues when upgrading to v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68101295/chart-js-date-issues-when-upgrading-to-v3)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69335353/chartjs-time-cartesian-axis-adapter-and-date-library-setup/69335631#69335631

Another one

Comment: Thanks all. I actually solved this one myself, as I was waiting for replies. Was I supposed to mark this solved in some way? (New-ish to posting here.) I'm really struggling with the chartjs documentation. I usually have to find examples that I can pilfer or just bang my head against my keyboard until the correct code gets typed! ;-)

Comment: If you've solved it yourself, write it up and post it as an answer so others can see how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so yes I figured out I was missing some files: Luxon 1.0, and the Luxon adapter (chartjs-adapter-luxon), available on GitHub (https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-luxon). I struggle with GitHub sometimes, plus I didn't want to link to any non-local files. I managed to find and view each file in a browser window, and then just saved each page's source as a plain text doc, which I named appropriately. Stashed those in the same local directory as my chart's HTML page and then linked each file to my chart's page in its HTML. My chart sprang to life and all is well. I take it there's a better way to get a file off of GitHub, but I couldn't figure that out. Apologies for the knumbskullery, but it worked...